# grant select column privileges to user on condition that users can only access column related to their id column - Oracle pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper, privileges

I got some tables:

**Book(bookId, libraryId, bookName, bookType);**

**BookType(bookType, typeName);**

**Library(LibrayId);**

**User(UserId);**

**BookBorrowed(BorrowId, LibraryId, UserId);**

**BorrowDetail(BorrowId, bookId)**

and a user created in **sqlDeveloper**, **C##DG**.

How to **GRANT privileges(select) ON BookBorrowed and User with UserId = 1(C##DG can only see and use SELECT the data on the 2 table whose UserId column is 1)**?.

Can you guys show me some examples?

Thanks you very much.

Comment: I don't see what the question has to do with PL/SQL programming or the SQL Developer or PL/SQL Developer desktop tools specifically. It seems like a general Oracle DBA question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper Oracle solution to this is [Virtual Private Database](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/using-oracle-vpd-to-control-data-access.html#GUID-06022729-9210-4895-BF04-6177713C65A7).

if that isn't an option, another way is to define views such as:

```
create view userBookBorrowed
   as select * from bookBorrowed bb
      join users u on (u.userid = bb.userid)
      where u.username = USER;
```

Then only grant the users access to the view, not the table.

Comment: I did what you told and when i logged in SQL Plus as C##DG and SELECT * FROM BOOKBROWED, it returns 2. What is the problem with print out SQL Plus? Can you explain to me, please?

Comment: It sounds like you need to `revoke select on bookborrowed from c##dg;`  The idea is that they only select from the new view, not the table.

Comment: i mean, when i SELECT * FROM userBookBorrowed on SQL Plus, it still returns 2.

Comment: That doesn't make sense if you've got the changes right - we are joining bookBorrowed to Users table on user_id, and then restricting to the Users row for the connected user.  There must only be one Users row with username = 'C##DG', and if that has userid=1 then only bookBorrowed  with userid=1 can be returned?

Comment: I understood. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as column-level privileges that you can grant or revoke. You need to implement Virtual Private Database policies for those kinds of filters or restrictions. See here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/using-oracle-vpd-to-control-data-access.html#GUID-06022729-9210-4895-BF04-6177713C65A7